# How to delete a session file in *public_html/writable/session* after destroying session and prevent getting wrong session data

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, codeigniter-4

I have a CodeIgniter 4 project.

When a user logins in and navigating through the website, at times the **session()->get()** will get a wrong session data thereby showing wrong user data because I use session to query user details from database.

This is how I set the session

```
$this->setUserSession($user);

    private function setUserSession($user)
    {
        $data = [
            
            
            'id' => $user['id'],
            'username' => $user['username'],
            'isLoggedIn' => true,
        ];

        session()->set($data);
    
        return true;
    }
```

I call it using **session()->get('id')**

And I destroy it using

```
public function logout()
    {
        session()->destroy();
        return redirect()->to('login');
    }
```

Please How can I prevent the session from getting a wrong session data?

Comment: *at times the session()->get() will get a wrong session data*, please explain how you come to this conclusion.

Comment: Mr. A will begin to see Mr. B account details

Comment: are you testing this in the same browser/device or with different devices/browsers for A and B?

Comment: different devices.

Comment: how are you making sure the user is logged it? And how are your getting the data about said user on the database. Please add those functions to your question.

Comment: I use session data to query user information from the database